# Can these three SQLITE INSERTS be combinded or improved?

Tags: sql, sqlite, insert

I have three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE "local" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL , "serialNumber" TEXT, "location" TEXT)

CREATE TABLE "setups" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL ,"hold" TEXT,"mode" INTEGER,"setTemp" REAL,"maxSTemp" REAL,"minSTemp" REAL,"units" TEXT,"heat" INTEGER,"heatMode" INTEGER,"fanMode" INTEGER,"fan" INTEGER,"cool" INTEGER)

CREATE TABLE "data" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL ,"humidity" REAL,"time" INTEGER,"filtChng" INTEGER,"indoorTemp" REAL,"outdoorTemp" REAL, "setups_id" INTEGER, "local_id" INTEGER)
```

Everytime I get a new entry I execute:

```
INSERT INTO local ('serialNumber') SELECT 'XXXX' WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM local WHERE serialNumber='XXXX')"

INSERT INTO setups ('hold','mode','setTemp','maxSTemp','minSTemp','units','heat','heatMode','fanMode','fan','cool') SELECT '00',1,74.0,74.0,74.0,'F',1,1,1,1,1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM setups WHERE hold='00' AND mode=1 AND setTemp=74.0 AND maxSTemp=74.0 AND minSTemp=74.0 AND units='F' AND heat=1 AND heatMode=1 AND fanMode=1 AND fan=1 AND cool=1)

 INSERT INTO data ('humidity','filtChng','time','indoorTemp','outdoorTemp',local_id,setups_id) SELECT 74.0,111111111,100,74.0,74.0,local.id,setups.id FROM local CROSS JOIN setups WHERE local.serialNumber='XXXX' AND setups.hold='00' AND setups.mode=1 AND setups.setTemp=74.0 AND setups.maxSTemp=74.0 AND setups.minSTemp=74.0 AND setups.units='F' AND setups.heat=1 AND setups.heatMode=1 AND setups.fanMode=1 AND setups.fan=1 AND setups.cool=1
```

What I am doing works, but seems slow and redundant/inefficient...

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can remove the "where not exists" part from the "local" insert if you use a unique constraint on the "serialNumber" field.  Be careful, this will throw a constraint violation instead of just not inserting the row.  So be sure to handle that in the application.

And though I assume it is, be sure that checking for duplicates is really necessary in your app.

Comment: Having duplicates would defeat the purpose (smaller database) of breaking the data up into three tables (otherwise, I could just use one table with all the values for every entry)...

Comment: I don't mean duplicates in the sense of repeating the data from one table in the other table(s), but as in having duplicate "setups" for the same "local".

Comment: I don't want to have any duplicate data.  My code populates the tables as desired, but I don't think it is doing it efficiently....